# ¿como soluciono un IndexError: list index out of range?

Tags: python, index

No logro ubicar de manera correcta el codigo, necesito que al pedir la funcion mostrar(zombies) me saque los datos de cada ciudad que le doy por la ubicacion en la lista

```
def crearZombies():
  print("--Creando los zombies en las ciudades --")
  a = int(input("Ingresa la cantidad de Zombies en Sabaneta "))
  b = int(input("Ingresa la cantidad de Zombies en Envigado "))
  c = int(input("Ingresa la cantidad de Zombies en Medellin "))
  d = int(input("Ingresa la cantidad de Zombies en Itagui "))
  zombies = [a, b, c, d]
  return zombies
  
def mostrar(zombies): 
  
 menu= f""" 
 S: {zombies[0]} | E: {zombies[1]} #Aqui aparece error
 M: {zombies[2]} | I: {zombies[3]}
 """
 return menu
 print(mostrar(zombies))

zombies=[]
crearZombies()
mostrar(zombies)#Aqui aparece error
```

Answer (score 2):

Hay un problema de [ámbito de variables](https://www.google.com/search?q=ambito+de+variables). `zombies` dentro de la función `crearZombies` no es la misma lista  que la que está afuera de la función.
Cuando una función tiene `return`, debe haber otra variable esperando el resultado. Para corregir el problema:

```py
# ... Aqui la funcion crearZombies()

def mostrar(zombies): 
    menu= f""" 
    S: {zombies[0]} | E: {zombies[1]}
    M: {zombies[2]} | I: {zombies[3]}
    """
    return menu

#zombies=[] # <-- crearZombies devuelve una lista, no sería necesaria esta linea
zombies = crearZombies()
print(mostrar(zombies))
```